# Draw Drawdown Chart in Studio R

Tags: r

I have downloaded in R the stock price data from Netfilx:

```
library(tidyquant)
library(timetk)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(corrplot)
library(tidyr)

netflix <- tq_get("NFLX",                    
                  from = '2009-01-01',
                  to = "2018-03-01",
                  get = "stock.prices")

netflix %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = adjusted)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("Netflix since 2009") +
  labs(x = "Date", "Price") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "years", date_labels = "%Y") +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Adjusted Price") +
  theme_bw()
```

But now i want to draw a drawdown chart likt this picture. How can I do this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC5l8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can start withi this. Calculate drawdowns in percentage will depend on the stats you want to use it. Here is just an example with total values and a line with the mean drawdown.

```
# add drawdown to each date
nfdd <- netflix %>% arrange(date) %>% mutate(drawdown=adjusted-lag(adjusted))

# calculate mean drawdown
meandd <- mean(nfdd$drawdown[nfdd$drawdown<=0], na.rm = TRUE)

# change drawdown >=0 to 0
nfdd2 <- nfdd %>% mutate(drawdown = ifelse(drawdown>=0, 0, drawdown))
meandd2 <- mean(nfdd2$drawdown[nfdd2$drawdown<=0], na.rm = TRUE)

# plot
nfdd2 %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = date, y = drawdown)) +
        geom_line(color="blue", alpha=0.7) +
        ggtitle("Netflix drawdown since 2009") +
        labs(x = "Date", "Drawdown") +
        scale_x_date(date_breaks = "years", date_labels = "%Y") +
        labs(x = "Date", y = "Drawdown") +
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-10, 0)) +
        geom_hline(yintercept=meandd2, linetype="dashed", color="red", size=1)+
        theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks, that helps me already. But this looks not so nice. Do I have to connect each points for the drawdown chart for a better result?

Comment: You can do that easily: either you remove the drawdown values above 0 or you replace those values by 0. The values are there but in this chart I just stablised the scale_y_continuous to stop at 0.